# Recognizing a list from a text file

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have a text file, "blah.txt" and within it contains this data:

> blah1: [01,02,03]
>
> blah2: [01,02,03]

I can read through the file and put it into a list with this:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('blah.txt'),delimiter=":")
```

But [01,02,03] isn't recognized as a list, but as a string. Is there a short and simple way to make it so that it does recognize it as a list?

Full code:

```
import csv, operator
reader = csv.reader(open('file.txt'),delimiter=":")
sortedlist = sorted(reader, reverse=True)
for name, score in sortedlist:
    print(score)
```

**Edit:**

I can instead write the data as

> blah1:010203
>
> blah2:010203

and use this:

```
import csv, operator
reader = csv.reader(open('file.txt'),delimiter=":")
sortedlist = sorted(reader, reverse=True)
for name, score in sortedlist:
    score = [int(score[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(score), 2)]
    print(name, score)
```

However it isn't convenient to read from the text file directly (by person).

Comment: Ugly version might be `json.loads(score)`

Comment: @Torxed, I'm not quite sure what that does?

Comment: It will take a string `"[1,2,3]"` and convert it to a actual list object since it's in a JSON accepted format. JSON being sort of a protocol/variable type

Comment: If it is just to convert, you can simply eval(score) and it will transform the string into a list.

Comment: @Walter_Ritzel, if I use "eval(score)", I get this error:
`  File "<string>", line 1
    [01,02,03]
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid token`

Comment: So, it seems that left 0 is causing this.

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought `ast.literal_eval` was the right tool for this, but look what happens:

```
>>> literal_eval('[01,020,03]')
[1, 16, 3]
```

Since you probably don't want integers starting with zero to be interpreted in base 8, I don't think there's a much prettier solution than to split by comma:

```
>>> s = '[01,020,03]'
>>> [int(x) for x in s[1:-1].split(',')]
[1, 20, 3]
```

If you have a chance to write your integers without leading zeros to your file, `ast.literal_eval` wins again.

Comment: I encounter a SyntaxError: Invalid Token (sorry, amateur here)

Edit: I realise its because the numbers are being seen as octal numbers, any way to prevent this?

Comment: @PandaGod any chance you are mistakenly using the whole line and not just the "stringlist" part of it?

Comment: @timgeb No, I realised that it was because of the literal zero's, I think I can work around them so I'm gonna trash them and use ast.literal_eval, thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Say you have `"[01,02,03]"` stored as a string variable `s`. You can then do:

```
score = [int(x) for x in s.strip('[').strip(']').split(',')]
```

as long as there are no spaces in between the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The input (line.txt):

```
blah1: [01,02,03]
blah2: [01,02,03]
blah3: [01,02,03]
blah4: [01,02,03]
```

Process the file:

```
from collections import OrderedDict  # if you want to maintain the order

data = OrderedDict()

for line in open("list.txt").readlines():
    k, v = line.split(':')
    # from list (in string form), remove whitespace, remove brackets
    # turn the list (in string form) into a list
    data[k] = v.strip()[1:-1].split(',')
```

The result:

```
>>> data
OrderedDict([('blah1', ['01', '02', '03']), ('blah2', ['01', '02', '03']), 
('blah3', ['01', '02', '03']), ('blah4', ['01', '02', '03'])])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using, thanks @timgeb for the suggestion.

```
reader = csv.reader(open(file + '.txt'),delimiter=":")
data = {}
for name, score in reader:
    data[name] = sorted(ast.literal_eval(score), reverse=True)
```